How to trigger Finder's OneDrive extension's Copy Link action programatically
I use OneDrive quite extensively on macOS and one thing which I do quite often is copy the OneDrive link of some file into the clipboard, to share with others. Now instead doing this via mouse I would like to by able to do this programmatically via Automator or Alfred.
I tried to play around with AppleScript but couldn't get it to work. Any idea how this could be accomplished?


This is not "programmatically" but using only keyboard. While in Finder on desired file invoke context menu with ctrl+Enter (requires Sequoia) and navigate to Copy Link using down arrow (I personally have Karabiner Elements complex modifications for vim-like navigation from keyboard)

@AivarPaalberg, Yeah that could indeed be a way to automate it quickly via keyboard, thanks for sharing! In my case I often find the file using the Alfred's search, so I would like to make a Alfred's Universal Action, meaning I would like to trigger this not from Finder, but via Alfred search and for this I need to program it, e.g. via AppleScript.
